# AVPictureInPictureController cannot activate programmatically during a scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, swift5, avkit, picture-in-picture

I have a video in a cell, if I put it in PIP mode with the button everything works fine but if I do it programmatically when the cell go out of screen doesn't not automatically put in PIP mode, can just activate it via a button?

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    guard let cell = self.playerCell, self.playerController != nil else {
        return
    }
    
    let rect = self.view.convert(cell.frame, from: scrollView)
    if rect.origin.y < 0, self.pipController == nil {
        self.pipController = self.startPictureInPicture()
    }
}

func startPictureInPicture() -> AVPictureInPictureController? {
    guard AVPictureInPictureController.isPictureInPictureSupported() else {
        return nil
    }
    
    let layer = AVPlayerLayer(player: self.playerController.player)
    try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
    if let pipController = AVPictureInPictureController(playerLayer: layer) {
        if pipController.isPictureInPicturePossible {
            pipController.startPictureInPicture()
        } else {
            pipController.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "isPictureInPicturePossible", options: [.new, .initial], context: nil)
        }
    }
    
    return nil
}

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if keyPath == "isPictureInPicturePossible", let pipController = object as? AVPictureInPictureController, pipController.isPictureInPicturePossible {
        pipController.startPictureInPicture()
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**: the debug console always show a warning *Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <UIViewController>*. but this I have solved with:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
    pipController.startPictureInPicture()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As per Apple's guidelines, we should not start PIP mode without user's action.

> Only begin Picture in Picture playback in response to user interaction and never programmatically. The App Store review team rejects apps that fail to follow this requirement.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/adopting_picture_in_picture_in_a_custom_player

I would suggest you create your own custom PIP view inside the app to avoid rejection.